# How do I handle this kind of condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text field which  has the regex validation and it should not accept value "0".
whether I need to use "and" condition (or) "OR CONDITION" in the below if condition

```
var regex = /^[0-9][0-9]{0,3}$|^[0-9][0-9]{0,3}[\.][0-9]$/;
if(!regex.test($('#text1').val()))
{  
   alert("please ");     
}
```

Comment: This has a **lot** more to do with JavaScript than jQuery. All you're doing with jQuery is retrieving the value; the regex and test are just JavaScript on its own. Added the `javascript` tag (but didn't remove the `jquery` one; probably should have, but...)

Comment: So you're looking for a number in a range between 0 and 10000?

Comment: I went ahead and removed the tags. This has so little to do with jQuery it had to be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you need to do is make sure the user didn't enter `0`, couldn't you forego the regex and just do something like this?

```
var v = parseFloat($('#text1').val());
if (v == 0 ) {
  alert("please");
}
```

Comment: Definitely - but having this line just before (or after) the regex will catch anything that comes out to 0.

Comment: Yeah, you need `parseFloat`, not `parseInt`.

Comment: @Luke: *"but having this line just before (or after) the regex will catch anything that comes out to 0"* Quick, what's the return value of `parseInt("0.2")`?